# How can I move an ssl certificate from one domain to another?

Tags: ssl, vps

I have two websites/domains hosted on godaddy(vps) and I erroneously renewed SSL for the wrong domain. Is there a way I can undo this or transfer the SSLto the correct domain?

Comment: You'll probably have to email GoDaddy Support to help you out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact GoDaddy and get them to revoke the certificate and re-issue you a new one. I dont think StackOverflow can help you in this regard - this is a GoDaddy Customer Service issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once you buy an **SSL Certificate** for a domain, that domain name can't be replaced with another one. If you have purchased a Multi-Domain SSL certificate, then you can add the new domains as the SAN domain.

As you have **reissue the SSL Certificate** for the wrong domain, the only solution is.

**Cancel your order** and **ask for refund** to GoDaddy, then again reissue your SSL certificate for the domain name which you were actually wishing.